# Using class name scope twice when defining member method

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I accidentally used the class name scope twice when defining a class member method, and was surprised it worked:

```
class A {
    public:
        void f();
};

void A::A::f() {}
```

Why does `void A::A::f(){}` work? I thought only `void A::f(){}` should work?